# Is it possible to install an over 2TB HDD CentOS on Hetzner?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, centos, grub

Wanted to just check here before I open a ticket at [Hetzner](https://www.hetzner.de/en/). I just got a server from Hetzner with 2x 3TB. I want to set them up in a RAID 0.

I’ve ran the “Installimage” command once in rescue-mode, then I am presented with the config file. So I set `SWRAIDLEVEL` to `0`.

When I save the config and try and install CentOS I get the following message:

CentOS only supports MS-DOS partition tables when using grub. We changed your "all" partition table to match the 2TB limit

In their FAQ it says to use GRUB2 if you have over 2TB HDDs and I’ve tried that but it says unsupported bootloader.

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

I found one way of doing this (using instructions from [hetzner wiki](http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Festplattenaustausch_im_Software-RAID/en#Drives_with_GPT) ). The goal is to move from MBR to GPT:

1. ssh into rescue mode
2. issue command `sgdisk -R /dev/sdb /dev/sda`
3. go to Hetzner robot and activate VNC session
4. reboot the rescue mode - this will disconnect the ssh session
5. Launch VNC session. This should start the GUI mode install of your OS. For me it was CentOS 6.5 and this time around, I was able to use full 2 x 3 TB in LVM instead of being restricted to 2 TB max.

Perhaps after reboot, VNC is unnecessary.. I didn't verify. If someone does verify, please reply back so I will use that method next time.

One important thing to note in the VNC installation is whether after you set your partitions - CentOS complains about installing GPT on an incompatible BIOS/non-EFI (something like that) partition. If you get this error, likely, you wont be able to install GPT with these 3TB drives. I observed that I got such an error. I returned the server and ordered another one. Same instructions worked on another server.

Comment: Very good solution, using VNC to install the distribution is the key!